# No Wi-Fi adapter when running Ubuntu 20.04 on LENOVO V145-15AST

Tags: wireless, 20.04, lenovo, realtek-wireless, ubuntu-drivers

Ubuntu works well except that no Wi-Fi adapter can be found. The installed wireless network card *Realtek 8821CE Wireless Lan 802.11ac PCI-E NIC* works OK with Windows.

I have installed `linux-oem-osp1` and `linux-firmware`, but still Ubuntu cannot find any Wi-Fi adapter.

Are you able to help?

Tanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Connect to internet and run in a terminal

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Thanks. Module rtlwifi-new/0.6 are now installed on kernel 5.4.0-52-generic/x86_64. But unfortunately still no wi-fi adapter can be found.

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: It was enabled. I got a guideline now to install with this. But it didn't work. I then disabled it and then installed. If I try to install again I get the information that it is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
cd rtw88
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```

Comment: This is not a good way to install the driver. You'll have to reinstall it after each kernel upgrade.